# System.Web.HttpException: 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel/*;base64,is not a valid virtual path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, webforms

I am trying to

- convert a SqlDataReader To Yogesh.WorkBook.XML Excel Workbook File
- then convert it to byte array
- then after saving it with binary format in Database
- retrieve it from database
- then convert it to base64 string
- then download it with context.Response.WriteFile instead of retreiving it from IoStream
- so that user can download it in Excel format.

But unfortunately it throws this Exception :

Exception Details:

> System.Web.HttpException: 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel/*;base64,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...'
> is not a valid virtual path.

```cs
public class GetFile : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string fileName = context.Request.QueryString["FileName"];
            int fileCode = int.Parse(fileName);
            BOLAmlakFiles bOLAmlakFiles = new BOLAmlakFiles();
            var tools = new Tools();
            var file = bOLAmlakFiles.GetFileByCode(fileCode);
            string fileType = context.Request.QueryString["FileType"];
            var fileContent = "";
            if (fileType == ".xls")
            {
                fileContent = tools.ConvertByteToExcel(file.Content.ToArray());
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileType)) return;
            if (fileName.Contains("/") || fileName.Contains("\\") || fileName.Contains("..")) return;

            string sContentType = "";
            switch (fileType)
            {
                case ".dwf":
                    sContentType = "application/x-dwf";
                    break;
                case ".pdf":
                    sContentType = "application/pdf";
                    break;
                case ".doc":
                    sContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
                    break;
                case ".ppt":
                case ".pps":
                    sContentType = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
                    break;
                case ".xls":
                    sContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    break;
                default:
                    sContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                    break;
            }

            string path = "";

            if (context.Request.QueryString["IsReport"] == "1")
                //path = string.Format("{0}\\ReportResult\\{1}", HttpContext.Current.Application["PicPath"], fileName);
                //path = string.Format("{0}\\ReportResult\\{1}", HttpContext.Current.Application["PicPath"], fileName);
                path = fileContent;
            else
                path = string.Format("{0}\\NewsFiles\\{1}", HttpContext.Current.Application["PicPath"], fileName);

            //path = path.Replace("\\\\", "\\");

            context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            context.Response.WriteFile(path);

        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
 public static int ExportToXMLBinary2(int reportCode, SqlDataReader sqlReader, bool hasHeader)
        {
            string randomName = "";
            int code = 0;
            try
            {
                ExcelXmlWorkbook book = new ExcelXmlWorkbook();
                book.Properties.Author = "Raahabr";
                Yogesh.ExcelXml.Worksheet sheet = book[0];
                sheet.Name = "";
                sheet.FreezeTopRows = 4;
                //  sheet.Border.LineStyle = Yogesh.ExcelXml.Borderline.Continuous;
                //  sheet.Border.Sides = BorderSides.Bottom;

                int startCol = 3;
                int currentRow = 3;

                int colCount = sqlReader.FieldCount;
                if (hasHeader)
                {
                    ReportBOL rbol = new ReportBOL();
                    Dictionary<string, string> cNames = rbol.getColumnNames(reportCode);

                    for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
                    {
                        string head = sqlReader.GetName(i);
                        string value = (cNames.ContainsKey(head)) ? cNames[head] : head;
                        if (value.ToString() == "")
                            value = head;
                        sheet[currentRow + i, currentRow].Value = value;
                        sheet[currentRow + i, currentRow].Border.LineStyle = Borderline.Continuous;
                        sheet[currentRow + i, currentRow].Border.Sides = BorderSides.All;
                    }
                }
                currentRow++;

                if (sqlReader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
                        {
                            sheet[startCol + i, currentRow].Value = sqlReader[i].ToString();
                            sheet[startCol + i, currentRow].Border.LineStyle = Borderline.Continuous;
                            sheet[startCol + i, currentRow].Border.Sides = BorderSides.All;
                        }
                        currentRow++;
                    }
                }
                randomName = getRandomName();
                var tools = new Tools();
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    book.Export(stream);
                    var content = stream.ToArray();
                    code = tools.UploadExcelFileToDatabase(randomName,content);
                }
                book.DeleteSheet(0);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // System.IO.File.WriteAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/err.txt"), randomName + ";" + reportDefaultPath + "\r\n" + ex.Message + "\r" + ex.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlReader.Close();
                sqlReader.Dispose();
            }
            return code;
        }
```

```cs
public class NewMoshaverRegedContracts : IHttpHandler
    {
        private static int reportCode = 2138;
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                bool exportToExcel = context.Request.Form["ExportToXML"] != null;

                NameValueCollection ReceivedData = null;
                if (exportToExcel)
                    ReceivedData = context.Request.Form;
                else
                    ReceivedData = context.Request.QueryString;

                int HcShowGridCode = 2;
                string sHcShowGridCode = ReceivedData["HcShowGridCode"].ToString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sHcShowGridCode))
                    HcShowGridCode = int.Parse(sHcShowGridCode);

                string fromDate = ReceivedData["FromDate"];
                string toDate = ReceivedData["ToDate"];

                int MoshaverAmlakCode = 0;
                string shenaseMoshaver = ReceivedData["ShenaseMoshaver"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(shenaseMoshaver))
                    MoshaverAmlakCode = int.Parse(shenaseMoshaver);

                int ContractVal = 0;
                string contractType = ReceivedData["ContractType"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contractType))
                    ContractVal = int.Parse(contractType);
                if(ContractVal == -1) 
                    ContractVal = 0;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromDate) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(toDate)
                    && string.IsNullOrEmpty(shenaseMoshaver) && 
                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(contractType))
                    return;

                int pageSize = 0;
                int page = 1;
                if (!exportToExcel)
                {
                    pageSize = int.Parse(ReceivedData["rows"].ToString());
                    try
                    {
                        page = int.Parse(ReceivedData["page"].ToString());
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        page = 1;
                    }
                }
                
                string reportName = "";
                int reportCode = 0;
                DataSet ds = null;
                ReportBOL bol = new ReportBOL();
                if (exportToExcel)
                {
                    //reportName = Commons.ExportToXML(reportCode, bol.NewMoshaverRegedContractsReader(-1, -1, fromDate, toDate, MoshaverAmlakCode, ContractVal, HcShowGridCode), true);
                    reportCode = Commons.ExportToXMLBinary2(reportCode, bol.NewMoshaverRegedContractsReader(-1, -1, fromDate, toDate, MoshaverAmlakCode, ContractVal, HcShowGridCode), true);
                }
                else
                    ds = bol.NewMoshaverRegedContracts(page, pageSize, fromDate, toDate, MoshaverAmlakCode, ContractVal, HcShowGridCode);
                if (!exportToExcel)
                {
                    int totalRecords = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                    DataTable data = ds.Tables[0];
                    int totalPage = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalRecords / (double)pageSize);

                    if (page > totalPage)
                    {
                        page = totalPage;
                        ds = bol.NewMoshaverRegedContracts(page, pageSize, fromDate, toDate, MoshaverAmlakCode, ContractVal, HcShowGridCode);
                        data = ds.Tables[0];
                    }
                    string str = Commons.getJSON(totalPage, page, totalRecords, data, false);

                    context.Response.ContentType = "json";

                    context.Response.Write(str);
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text";
                    //context.Response.Write(reportName);
                    context.Response.Write(reportCode.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

```cs
 public int UploadExcelFileToDatabase(string name, byte[] excelByte)
    {
        BOLAmlakFiles bOLAmlakFiles = new BOLAmlakFiles();
        var resultCode = bOLAmlakFiles.InsertFile(name, excelByte, "Report",
                    ".xls");
        return resultCode;
    }
```

```
  public string ConvertByteToExcel(byte[] ByteExcel)
    {
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ByteExcel);
        var ExcelSrc = string.Format($"data:application/vnd.ms-excel/*;base64,{base64}");
        return ExcelSrc;
    }
```

Comment: What gave you the idea that all English words start with a capital letter? I've tried to make it more readable.